# How to generate number sequence of base 3

Tags: algorithm, binary, numbers, radix

I am trying to write a program to generate a number sequence of base 3. The method will take an input n and will print all the sequence from 0 to n.

The problem is that I am not sure how to write this. I tried searching but didn't get any relevant links. Can someone provide me the concept of how to do it and then I will code this.

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Please be more clear about your question. Are you asking for a number sequence of length n where all the numbers are base 3 numbers.

Comment: It's always a good idea to include example input with expected output in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the entire solution to your problem, but it gives you the core of what you need to work with. You'll have to wrap it in a function and build a loop to call that function for each number.

Assuming you're given a number, you can get the characters for the base-n representation pretty simply. For example:

```
desiredBase = 3;
number = 42;

do
{
    digit = number % desiredBase;
    write(digit);
    number = number / desiredBase;
} (while number > 0)
```

That's going to output the digits in reverse order, but you get the idea. You'll have to buffer them and then reverse the digits before outputting.

Oh, and there's a little bit of weirdness for negative numbers.

You might look for the source of the C function `itoa`, which will create the base-n representation of a given number. You should be able to find that easy enough with a Google search.

Or just look up "number base conversion" and you'll get lots of hits.

Comment: why n is divided by desired base ? Sorry if this question is too silly, but I need to know this.

Comment: @hgupta: Consider the steps if you're converting to base 10. First you take `42 % 10` and get 2. So you output the digit 2. Then you divide by 10 and your number is 4. You take `4 % 10` and get 4. You output 4, divide by 10, and your number is 0. You're done.